# fgets reads three ''\n" when my file begins with text

Tags: c, fgets, strcmp

Here's the code of my function:

```
char str[DIM_STR];
char tipo[DIM_TIPO];
int j=0, var=0;

for(j=0; j<DIM_STR; j++)
    str[j]='\0';

for(j=0; j<DIM_TIPO; j++)
    tipo[j]='\0';


while(fgets(str, DIM_STR, fp)!=NULL){

    if(str[0]=='\n')
    {
        printf("line %d,LINHA EM BRANCO\n", var);
    }

    else
    {
        sscanf(str, "%s", tipo);

        if(strcmp(tipo, "JANELA")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d %d", tipo, &info_janela[DIM_JANELA][DIM_X], &info_janela[DIM_JANELA][DIM_Y]);
        }

        if(strcmp(tipo, "X")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d %d", tipo, &info_janela[DIM_FIS_X][X_FIS_MAX], &info_janela[DIM_FIS_X][X_FIS_MIN]);
        }

        if(strcmp(tipo, "Y")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d %d", tipo, &info_janela[DIM_FIS_Y][Y_FIS_MAX], &info_janela[DIM_FIS_Y][Y_FIS_MIN]);
        }

        if(strcmp(tipo, "C")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d %d", tipo, &info_janela[CENTRO_REF][X_0], &info_janela[CENTRO_REF][Y_0]);
        }

        if(strcmp(tipo, "ESTRELAS")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d", info_tamanho[ESTRELAS].tipo, &info_tamanho[ESTRELAS].tamanho);

        }

        if(strcmp(tipo, "PLANETAS")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d", info_tamanho[PLANETAS].tipo, &info_tamanho[PLANETAS].tamanho);

        }

        if(strcmp(tipo, "ASTEROIDES")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d", info_tamanho[ASTEROIDES].tipo, &info_tamanho[ASTEROIDES].tamanho);

        }

        if(strcmp(tipo, "FRAGMENTOS")==0){

            sscanf(str, "%s %d", info_tamanho[FRAGMENTOS].tipo, &info_tamanho[FRAGMENTOS].tamanho);

        }

    }

    var++;

}
```

list of defines:

```
#define DIM_TIPO 10
#define DIM_INFO_CORPOS 4
#define DIM_STR 100

#define DIM_JANELA 0
#define DIM_X 0
#define DIM_Y 1

#define DIM_FIS_X 1
#define X_FIS_MIN 0
#define X_FIS_MAX 1

#define DIM_FIS_Y 2
#define Y_FIS_MIN 0
#define Y_FIS_MAX 1

#define CENTRO_REF 3
#define X_0 0
#define Y_0 1

#define ESTRELAS 0
#define PLANETAS 1
#define ASTEROIDES 2
#define FRAGMENTOS 3
```

This is the file:

```
JANELA 600 400

X 1000 -1000
Y 900 -900

C 300 200

ESTRELAS 20
PLANETAS 10
ASTEROIDES 6
FRAGMENTOS 3
```

It starts with text - JANELA ..., so why is it reading 3 blank lines first?

Here's the output:

```
line 1,BLANK LINE
line 4,BLANK LINE
line 6,BLANK LINE
600
400
-1000
1000
-900
900
300
200
```

EDIT: Here's the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ky1ctic8f35y81j/sim_config.txt?dl=0

Comment: Look at the content of the input file using a hex-dumper/-editor.

Comment: Also: How is `str` defined?

Comment: And after those three new-lines, what do you get then?

Comment: @alk `str` is defined as `char str[DIM_STR]`, DIM_STR being 60.
After the three new-lines, I get the correct values.

Comment: Are you on Windows using notepad to look into a file created on UNIX?

Comment: @alk I'm using textEdit on a mac.

Comment: Are you sure things are not getting printed in a different order than you expect? Create a var `int line_num = 0` and increment it with each iteration of the loop. Then change to: `printf("Line %d, BLANK LINE\n\n", line_num);`

Comment: Maybe you should check how your displaying the file. Eg. textEdit should let you select the line endings, also do the cases ie '\n' print one thing '\r\n' print something else. Also upload the file so somebody we can see the actual characters.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm getting the blank lines in lines 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I added the input file in the main thread.

Comment: Just turn this into a compilable program now. With everything including your file id, and declarations. The input looks fine.

Comment: My bet goes on that your aren't opening the file you intend to open ... ;-)

Comment: With the little information you provide and assuming `...some code...` doesn't printf anything, all I can conclude is that your program's output is expected. There are 3 blank lines and therefore it displays three times `BLANK LINE`. So where is the problem ??

Comment: I get "Line 2 BLANK LINE, Line 5 BLANK LINE, Line 7 BLANK LINE" as expected. Where are you incrementing `line_num`? It should be the first line in the `while` loop: `line_num += 1;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yeah you were right, it was in the wrong place but it prints all of them in a row when i printf other stuff on the "some code" part

Comment: Based on latest edit: There are no `printf` statements in the `else` block! Your code is doing exactly what it should be. Whatever `'printf` statements are printing those numbers in your example output happen **after** the `while` loop has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Just pasted your file contents(from the file in dropbox) in a new gedit window and saw there are 3 newlines before the word JANELA. When downloaded the file did not show any blank line and the output of your fragment was also not blank lines so download the file from dropbox and use it.
my code:

```
FILE *fp=fopen("sim_config.txt","a+");

char * str=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)!=NULL){

    if(strcmp(str,"\n")==0 || (strcmp(str,"\r\n")==0))
    {
        printf("BLANK LINE\n\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("ok\n");
    }
  }
}
```

output:
ok
ok
BLANK LINE

BLANK LINE

ok
ok
ok
ok
BLANK LINE

ok
ok
BLANK LINE

ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
///no blank lines

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: but at least `fgets()` won't overwrite beyond the end of the buffer that was allocated!  You're entirely correct, of course: the size given to `fgets()` should be the size of the allocated buffer.  Or the buffer should be changed to `char str[4096];` or something similar and then use the existing call to `fgets()`.